# Existence of a scalar

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Suppose I have a vector $u\in\mathbb{R}^s$ with strict positive entries. Furthermore there is a vector $q\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times s}$. I know that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with

$$x\cdot q=0\Rightarrow u^TA^Tx =0$$

Where $x\cdot q$ is the scalar product between $x$ and $q$. Why does it follow that there is a scalar $\alpha$ such that

$$u^TA^T=\alpha q$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation $x\cdot q=0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ implies $q$ is perpendicular to some subspace of $\mathbb R^{n-1}$. It states that for these $x$ in that subspace, $Au$ is also perpendicular to them, *viz*. $Au$ is perpendicular to that subspace. Then both $q$ and $Au$ lie on the one-dimension complementary space of that subspace, which colinear is required. That is there exists always a scalar $\alpha$ such that $Au=\alpha q$.